# getting error while executing spring boot with wizzn/keycloak:14

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, jboss, keycloak

After PC get restarted I am unable to start my spring boot gradle application.

Used Spring boot version 2.7.0,
docker application version is 4.12.0 (85629) ,
Mac os version 12.6 (21G115)

Previously it was working without any error, now I am unable to execute bootrun from IntelliJ.

docker-compose.yml is as below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: wizzn/keycloak:14
    ports:
      - '18080:8080'
    container_name: keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./docker/keycloak/realm-export.json:/tmp/realm-export.json
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm-export.json
```

IntelliJ console error log:

```
console-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDconsole-pattern_IS_UNDEFINEDorg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.AdminToolApplication.main(AdminToolApplication.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [jp/co/abc/english/admintool/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1243)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.saml2.Saml2LoginConfigurer.getBeanOrNull(Saml2LoginConfigurer.java:431)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.saml2.Saml2LoginConfigurer.getSharedOrBean(Saml2LoginConfigurer.java:422)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.saml2.Saml2LoginConfigurer.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(Saml2LoginConfigurer.java:291)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.saml2.Saml2LoginConfigurer.init(Saml2LoginConfigurer.java:232)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.saml2.Saml2LoginConfigurer.init(Saml2LoginConfigurer.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration.configure(SecurityConfiguration.java:58)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43e0a161.CGLIB$configure$0(<generated>)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43e0a161$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77ca6764.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43e0a161.configure(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Caused by: org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation(RelyingPartyRegistrations.java:86)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration.getRelyingPartyRegistration(SecurityConfiguration.java:75)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration.lambda$relyingPartyRegistrationRepository$0(SecurityConfiguration.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(SecurityConfiguration.java:45)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43e0a161.CGLIB$relyingPartyRegistrationRepository$1(<generated>)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43e0a161$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77ca6764.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at jp.co.abc.english.admintool.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43e0a161.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:903)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:726)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:900)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:726)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1688)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation(RelyingPartyRegistrations.java:79)
    ... 93 common frames omitted

> Task :bootRun FAILED

Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

After tying different settings, finally it is working.
I have updated keycloak image in docker-compose.yml as below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
    ports:
      - '18080:8080'
    container_name: keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./docker/keycloak/realm-export.json:/tmp/realm-export.json
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm-export.json
```

Comment: Conclusion: don't use strange images from nonames. It can be also dangerous from security perspective.